# Venn diagram - not enough space for labels

Tags: r

That's the code which I use for generating venn diagram. Do you know any solution how can I make it easier to read ?

```
 # Make data
    v3 <- venn.diagram(list(A=vec_EOD_total, B=vec_EON_total), filename=NULL, fill=c("red", "green"), cex.prop=NULL, cex=1.5, cat.cex= 1.5, alpha = c(0.5, 0.5), cat.fontface = 4, lty = 2)
    png("Overlap.png", width=4, height=4, units='in', res=150)
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(v3)
    dev.off()
```

[image]

Is it possible to put the number 241 from green data set in the same way as number 28 (using line) ?

One more question. Which part of the code makes a label of data set in italics ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `ext.percent` option you can specify the proportion that a partial area has to be smaller than to trigger external text placement.

```
library(VennDiagram)
v3 <- venn.diagram(list(A=1:2309, B=29:2550), filename=NULL, fill=c("red", "green"), 
       cex.prop=NULL, cex=1.5, cat.cex= 1.5, alpha = c(0.5, 0.5), 
       cat.fontface = 4, lty = 2, ext.percent=.2)
png("Overlap.png", width=5, height=4, units='in', res=150)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v3)
dev.off()
```

[image]

`cat.fontface` option controls fontface for each category name (1 = plain, 2 = bold, 3 = italic, 4 = bold italic).